# Jersey and Java 8 (Lambda expression)

Tags: java, rest, lambda, jersey, java-8

I use Jersey version 1.18.1 (com.sun.jersey), Spring and Java 8. If I put a Java 8 Lambda expression in a REST service, it crashes. If I remove the lambda expression, it works.

```
@Service
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    public String hello() {
        new ArrayList<String>().stream().filter((str) -> str.length() > 0);
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

I use **com.sun.jersey** (1.18.1 version).

Full stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet jersey-serlvet java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52264
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:1976)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:464)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:420)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
```

Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java 8 Lambda Expression Within REST Service not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917462/java-8-lambda-expression-within-rest-service-not-working)

Comment: Yes, but this solution does not work. I have tried it.

Comment: @Malahov so you tried with Jersey 2.7+ and got the same issue?

Comment: For com.sun.jersey last version 1.18.1. I didn't try org.glassfish.jersey.

Comment: any luck ? Ican't make it work with the latest jersey dependencies

Answer (score 10):

Jersey 1.18 is not compatible with java 8. They added java 8 compatibility since 1.19.

If you take a look at the Jersey 1.19 release notes, you can see the introduced the jdk8 support.

https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/releases/tag/1.19

Quoting the 1.19 tag:

> Thanks to @cowwoc you're able to run Jersey 1.x applications on JDK8

To fix this you have to upgrade Jersey to 1.19 or downgrade java 8 to 7.

Answer (score 3):

We had similar problem. Also **com.sun.jersey** in use.

After migration to the newest version (19.1) all works.
So simply please upgrade to the newest version.