# Exception when deploying on glassfish: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9578

Tags: java, exception, jersey, glassfish, hk2

when I deploy my war file on tomcat it is ok but when I deploy it on glassfish it gives the exception, I searched but found no result how to solve this.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9578
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
...............

[#|2018-10-07T15:19:22.345+0330|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app|#]

[#|2018-10-07T15:19:25.182+0330|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestController' defined in file [E:\glassfish3-Reservation\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\myproject\WEB-INF\classes\com\company\controller\TestController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Answer (score 3):

**Your best option is to update your Glassfish server if you can. Your version 3.1.2 is way too old, the current one is 5.0.**

Another option would be to look for Lambda expressions in the TestController class and to remove or replace them with standard code.

This exception seems to occur when you are using Lambda expressions or newer Java bytecode with a version of `asm.jar` which is too old. This is related to your old version of Glassfish which comes bundled with Jersey 1.x which has bundled `asm.jar` 3.1. This version seems to be not fully compatible with Java8 or newer bytecode.

**More related information:**

- [Strange java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown on jetty startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496338/strange-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-thrown-on-jetty-startup/26496604#26496604)
- [Java 8 Lambda Expression Within REST Service not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917462/java-8-lambda-expression-within-rest-service-not-working)
- [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using Java 8 language features](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/187)